# How to stop asyncio loop with multiple tasks

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I can't figure how to stop loop after one task is finished. In sample when WsServe count to 5 I expect loop to close. But instead stop I got ***RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import asyncio

async def rxer():
    i=0
    while True:
        i+=1
        print ('Rxer ',i)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def WsServe():
    for i in range(5):
        print ('WsServe',i)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    print ('Finish')
    loop.stop()
    loop.close()

loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(rxer())
loop.run_until_complete(WsServe())
loop.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error comes from calling `loop.close()` from inside the loop. You don't need to bother with `loop.close()`, `loop.stop()` is quite sufficient to stop the loop. `loop.close()` is only relevant when you want to ensure that all the resources internally acquired by the loop are released. It is not needed when your process is about to exit anyway, and removing the call to `loop.close()` indeed eliminates the error.

But also, `loop.stop()` is incompatible with `run_until_complete()`. It happens to work in this code because the coroutine returns immediately after calling `loop.stop()`; if you added e.g. an `await asyncio.sleep(1)` after `loop.stop()`, you'd again get a (different) `RuntimeError`.

To avoid such issues, I suggest that you migrate to the newer `asyncio.run` API and avoid both `run_until_complete` and `stop`. Instead, you can just use an event to terminate the main function, and the loop with it:

```
# rxer() defined as before

async def WsServe(stop_event):
    for i in range(5):
        print ('WsServe',i)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    print ('Finish')
    stop_event.set()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(rxer())
    stop_event = asyncio.Event()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(WsServe(stop_event))
    await stop_event.wait()

asyncio.run(main())

# python 3.6 and older:
#asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: can't use asyncio.run as require higher python version as I have.

Comment: @eSlavko You can easily replace `asyncio.run(main())` with `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())` and everything else can stay the same.

Comment: that's doesn't work. It throws error.    asyncio.create_task(rxer())
AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'create_task'

Comment: @eSlavko I've now amended the answer to create task in a way which works with older Python.

Comment: still doesnt work.     asyncio.create_task(WsServe(stop_event))
AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'create_task'

Comment: @eSlavko I missed the other place where the task is created, sorry about that (I don't have Python 3.6 to test it myself). I've now amended the answer again and it should work. Also, feel free to change the code yourself, the change was just to avoid the new `asyncio.create_task(...)` with the older `asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Check commented lines of your implementation as below:

```
import asyncio

async def rxer():
    i=0
    while True:
        i+=1
        print ('Rxer ',i)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def WsServe():
    for i in range(5):
        print ('WsServe',i)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    print ('Finish')
    #loop.stop()
    #loop.close()


loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(rxer())
loop.run_until_complete(WsServe())
#loop.run_forever()
```

And here is the output:

```
Rxer  1
WsServe 0
Rxer  2
WsServe 1
Rxer  3
WsServe 2
Rxer  4
WsServe 3
Rxer  5
WsServe 4
Rxer  6
Finish
```